# OOP PHP Class calling function1()->function2() from one line call

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I am in a new quandary, and have been trying to work with it, I have gotten nothing but errors but I'm some what determined to learn how to do it, and after a bit of searching looks like it cannot be done the say that I want it to be.

In the class there are two or more functions(each can probably be called separably[sp]):

```
public function functionOne($some_var){
    some other code to be run;
}
public function functionTwo($some_other_var){
    some other code to be run after functionOne(), not called here;
}
```

From the caller (model):

```
$tClass = new TestClass();
$result = tClass->functionOne()->functionTwo();
echo $result;
```

Is this even possible from php? I know it works in frameworks like Laravel, which is where I learned about it. it would be nice... and so I am asking if I am doing it wrong? or ist it even possible, if it is where can i look for more as google had very very little information on the subject.

Comment: It's called a "fluent interface" with each method in the chain returning `$this`

Comment: @MarkBaker :: It worked Thank you , I also wanted to thank you for replying and telling me the correct name, it helped in subsequent google searched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and will always work as soon as your method is doing

```
return $this;
```

Most likely it should be a good practice to make all your setters fluent. I would tend to say the only method that cannot be fluent would be your getters, otherwise, all other methods are perfect fit for a fluent interface.

```
class calculator {
    private $result = 0;

    public multiplication($number) {
        $this->result *= $number;
        return $this;
    }

    public addition() {
        $this->result += $number;
        return $this;
    }

    /* ... */

    public getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$calculator = new calculator();
echo $calculator->addition(10)->multiplication(2)->getResult(); // 20
```

Comment: Let me look into it Thank you :)

Comment: It worked thanks - I tested and it resulted in a fixed call... Thank you for your reply, I wanted to also thank you for your replay and telling me what the correct way to reference what i was trying to do, I did some more googling and found ample reading on the topic :)